# Is every group $G$ a subgroup of index $2$ of some $\tilde G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Let $(G,f)$ be a group (so $f$ stands for the group operation), $H\lneq G$ and $\complement_GH:=G\setminus H$. Then:

\begin{alignat}{1}
&f(H,H)\subseteq H \\
&f(H,\complement_GH)\subseteq\complement_GH \\
&f(\complement_GH,H)\subseteq\complement_GH \\
&[G:H]=2 \Rightarrow f(\complement_GH,\complement_GH)\subseteq H \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

Reminiscent of this fact, I wonder whether a supergroup of $G$ can be built up, say $\tilde G$, such that $[\tilde G:G]=2$. Namely:

> Is every group $G$ a subgroup of index $2$ of some $\tilde G$?

I think that's true, based on the following.

---

Let $G$ be a group and $X_G$ a set such that:

1. $X_G\cap G=\emptyset$;
2. there is a bijection $\alpha\colon X_G\to G$.

Let's define $\tilde G:=G\cup X_G$ and $\cdot : \tilde G\times\tilde G \to \tilde G$ by:

> \begin{alignat}{1}
> &a)\space g\cdot h:=gh, \space\forall g,h \in G \\
> &b)\space g\cdot x:=\alpha^{-1}(g\alpha(x)), \space\forall g \in G, x\in X_G \\
> &c)\space x\cdot g:=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x)g), \space\forall g \in G, x\in X_G \\
> &d)\space x\cdot y:=\alpha(x)\alpha(y), \space\forall x,y\in X_G \\
> \tag 2
> \end{alignat}

- **Associativity**

It holds in $G$ by definition. Besides, $\forall g,h \in G, \forall x \in X_G$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(g\cdot h)\cdot x &= (gh)\cdot x \\
&= \alpha^{-1}(gh\alpha(x)) \\
\end{alignat}

and

\begin{alignat}{1}
g\cdot (h\cdot x) &= \alpha^{-1}(g\alpha(h\cdot x)) \\
&= \alpha^{-1}(g\alpha(\alpha^{-1}(h\alpha(x)))) \\
&= \alpha^{-1}(gh\alpha(x)) \\
\end{alignat}

whence:

$$g\cdot (h\cdot x) = (g\cdot h)\cdot x \tag 3$$

Likewise, $\forall g,h \in G, \forall x \in X_G$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(g\cdot x)\cdot h &= \alpha^{-1}(\alpha(g\cdot x)h) \\
&= \alpha^{-1}(\alpha(\alpha^{-1}(g\alpha(x)))h) \\
&= \alpha^{-1}(g\alpha(x)h) \\
\end{alignat}

and

\begin{alignat}{1}
g\cdot (x\cdot h) &= \alpha^{-1}(g\alpha(x\cdot h)) \\
&= \alpha^{-1}(g\alpha(\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x)h))) \\
&= \alpha^{-1}(g\alpha(x)h) \\
\end{alignat}

whence:

$$g\cdot (x\cdot h) = (g\cdot x)\cdot h \tag 4$$

Furthermore, $\forall g \in G, \forall x,y \in X_G$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(g\cdot x)\cdot y &= \alpha(g\cdot x)\alpha(y)\\
&= \alpha(\alpha^{-1}(g\alpha(x)))\alpha(y)\\
&= g\alpha(x)\alpha(y)\\
&= g(\alpha(x)\alpha(y))\\
&= g\cdot(\alpha(x)\alpha(y))\\
&= g\cdot(x\cdot y)\\
\tag 5
\end{alignat}

Finally, $\forall x,y,z \in X_G$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(x\cdot y)\cdot z &= (\alpha(x)\alpha(y))\alpha(z)\\
&= \alpha(x)(\alpha(y)\alpha(z)) \\
&= x\cdot(y\cdot z) \\
\tag 6
\end{alignat}

- **Unit**

Note that:

- by $(2$-$b)$: $\space$ $e\cdot x=\alpha^{-1}(e\alpha(x))=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x))=x, \space\forall x \in X_G$
- by $(2$-$c)$: $\space$ $x\cdot e=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x)e)=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x))=x, \space\forall x \in X_G$

and $e$ serves as unit throughout $\tilde G$.

- **Inverses**

Let's define:

$$x^{-1}:= \alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x)^{-1}), \forall x \in X_G \tag 7$$

Therefore, by $(2$-$d)$ and $(7)$:

- $\space$ $x\cdot x^{-1}=\alpha(x)\alpha(x^{-1})=\alpha(x)\alpha(\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x)^{-1}))=\alpha(x)\alpha(x)^{-1}=e, \space\forall x \in X_G$

and $x^{-1}$ serves as inverse of the element $x \in X_G$.

---

Seemingly, $\tilde G$, endowed with the operation $(2)$, is indeed a group, and $[\tilde G:G]=2$.

Comment: It seems okay to me.

Comment: It seems correct to me. Actually, what you have constructed is $G\times (\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})$ in which $G$ may be embedded via $g\mapsto (g,0)$. Nevertheless, you have been careful enough, so that $\widetilde{G}$ *really* contains $G$...

Comment: Maybe I missed something from your question, but wouldn't just taking a direct product with the cyclic group of order 2 work for your question?

Comment: @PaulPlummer Up to isomorphism, yes. I guess that the OP wants a real inclusion of sets.

Comment: @TMO. Yes, correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof seems fine to me.

---

An alternative proof is via group presentations.

If $G$ has as a presentation

$$\langle X\mid R\rangle,$$

then, for any symbol $\xi\notin G$, since $\Bbb Z_2$ has as a presentation

$$\langle \xi\mid \xi^2\rangle,$$

the group $G\times \Bbb Z_2$ has as a presentation

$$\langle X\cup\{\xi\}\mid R\cup\{\xi^2\}\cup\{ x\xi=\xi x\mid x\in X\}\rangle.$$

Then $G$ is a subgroup of $G\times\Bbb Z_2$ with index two.

Comment: Thank you, Shaun. As pointed out in my comment to Nicky's answer, the only difference is that $G$ is a subset of "my" $\tilde G$, while it's not of yours, though this was not a constraint in my question. I note that just for the records.

Answer (score 8):

Why not take $\tilde G = G \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, now I got aware of that, thanks. The only I can notice, is that $G$ is not a subset of your (and other commentors') $\tilde G$. Anyway, I admit that my question didn't mention that.

Comment: No problem, your effort was excellent and I gave you a +1.