# Obtaining $\mathbb{Z}_2$ from an arbitrary group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Given an arbitrary group $G$ (which may even be trivial), is there any (canonical) way to obtain the two-element group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ from $G$ by performing various operations on $G$, e.g. taking subgroups, (amalgamated) free products, (semi)direct products, quotient groups, etc.?

Comment: You can do it if and only if $G$ has either even order, or has elements of even order, or has an element of infinite order (provided you allow quotients of subgroups). None of these ways is canonical.

Comment: What about $(G/G)\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, i.e., quotient $G$ by itself to get the trivial group and then direct product with whatever group you want to end up with.

Comment: @YacoubKureh That's definitely a 'canonical' way to do what I want, although ideally I just want to use the group $G$ (and groups constructed only from $G$), rather than involving $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: If you don't want to involve $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (directly or indirectly), then @ArturoMagidin 's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this what you are looking for,  but every group $G$ can be "extended" to a supergroup $\tilde G$ such that $G\le \tilde G$, $[\tilde G:G]=2$ and $\tilde G\cong G\times \Bbb Z_2$. The construction is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3614000/810157).

Comment: Thanks; I don't think this is quite what I was looking for (and I appreciate that my question was somewhat vague), but it's certainly an interesting construction and may end up being relevant.