# $G$ as "seed" of a countable sequence.

Tags: group-theory

Whatever group $G$ is, the construction given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3614000/810157) gives rise to a supergroup, say $G_1$, in which $G$ has index $2$. Here truly $G\subseteq G_1$, though $G_1$ is a byproduct of $G$. By iterating the process, $G_1$ gives rise in turn to a super-supergroup(?), $G_2$, such that $[G_2:G_1]=2$, and so on. Thus, it is as if the given $G$ acted as "seed" of a countable sequence $G_0:=G\unlhd G_1\unlhd \dots\unlhd G_i\unlhd G_{i+1}\unlhd\dots$ (for $[G_{i+1}:G_i]=2$, $\forall i\in \Bbb N$), which depends solely on $G$ as a group. I just want to ask if this extrapolation is legitimate or, for some reason, undue.

Comment: What do you want this to do?  You always have the possibility that $G_n = G_{n-1} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Also, is your question is the linked construction valid?  The answers given confirm that it is.

Comment: But in that case $G_{n-1}$ is not a subgroup of $G_n$, since as sets $G_{n}\cap G_{n-1}=\emptyset$.

Comment: Right, but that's my question:  why do you need this?  I've never encountered a situation where having something up to isomorphism (in algebra) wasn't good enough.

Comment: In any case, if $H < G$ with $|G:H|=2$, and $H \cong H_0$, then we can easily construct a group $G_0$ with $H_0 < G_0$, $|G_0:H_0|=2$, and $G_0 \cong G$. Just let $H_0'$ be some set disjoint from $H$ with $|H_0'|=|H_0|$, and use the isomorphism $H_0 \to G_0$ and the structure of $G_0$ to define a group isomorphic to $G$ on the set $H_0 \cup H_0'$.

Comment: @Randall, No need, actually. I was curious about the possibility of such "countable extrapolation", but doubtful on its legitimacy because here I have a routine and not a $n$-dependent formula to which just apply induction.